# VBA Autofilter - delete only visible cells within table and not the entire row

Tags: vba, autofilter

I'm using autofilter to quickly delte empty rows, however I thought I could manage to delete only the cells within the current range and not the entire row by only using `delete(xlshiftup)` rather than `entirerow.delete`

The code below is what I've used:

```
With Range
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
    .offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete (xlShiftUp)
End with
```

Is this possible? I thought this would be the solution but for some reason it deletes all content i the remaining visible rows.

Comment: How are you setting the initial `Range`?  How many Columns wide is it? (Stick a `MsgBox "Now deleting " & cstr(.Columns.Count) & " columns from " & cstr(.Rows.Count-1) & " rows"` before the delete to get an alert)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reference filtered range, remove autofilter and delete referenced range:

```
With Range
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
    With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
        .Delete (xlShiftUp)
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Can't believe I didn't know about the `.parent` operator